# no symbols have been loaded for this document

Tags: asp.net, iis

My ASP.NET WAP project in VS 2008 is set to debug=true in the web config
The in solution's properties, all assemblies are set to option Debug in the Configuration Manager

I compiled and reran this site using IIS mode.  Not sure why I still get this.

I set my debug to the firefox process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't debug `firefox.exe` - debug `w3wp.exe` instead.  The `w3wp.exe` process is the worker process for IIS from your website's AppPool, this is the process that contains the AppDomain within which your assemblies are loaded.

The `firefox.exe` process is running the browser itself.